# Jquery fadeOut complete callback not running but the fadeIn callback is

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein, fadeout

EDIT: I have removed the newpage in fadeIn as I think it was confusing people. I want the newpage to fadeIn.

I've written a little site that runs as one page whilst looking like a traditional site. What I basically was trying to do was have the essential elements ie. nav, logo, footer etc. to be fixed to the viewport and have a selection of anchor points that the nav will link to. This all works fine but now trying to animate it I am having some difficulties.

Here is the HTML markup I'm working with:

```
<div id="wrap">

    <ul id="nav">

        <li><a class="start" href="#link1">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="start" href="#link2">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="start" href="#link3">Page 3</a></li>
        <li><a class="start" href="#link4">Page 4</a></li>

    </ul>

    <div class="contents">

    <div id="page" class="page1">

        <a class="finish" name="link1">page1</a>

    </div>

    <div id="page" class="page2">

        <a class="finish" name="link2">page2</a>

    </div>

    <div id="page" class="page3">

        <a class="finish" name="link3">page3</a>

    </div>

    <div id="page" class="page4">

        <a class="finish" name="link4">page4</a>

    </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 80%;
    z-index: 999;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

#wrap {
    width: 400%;
    height: 100%;
}

#page {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.page1 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.page2 {
    background-color: red;
}

.page3 {
    background-color: grey;
}

.page4 {
    background-color: white;
}

.finish {
    opacity: 0;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now this all works perfectly without Jquery, it just goes straight to the linked page.
The Jquery here is working soley with the .contents container.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        //On page load, .contents will be hidden for a clean fadIn animation. WORKING

        $('.contents').css('display', 'none');

        $('.contents').fadeIn(1000);


        //Clicking any nav link will initiate animation.

        $('.start').click(function(event) {

        //Stops default action of going straight to anchor.

        event.preventDefault();

        newLocation = this.href;

        //newpage on fadeOut activate as seen in the url bar but not returning there on fadeIn.    

        $('.contents').fadeOut(1000, newpage);

        //newpage on fadeIn is a debug to test of page will return to newlacation. Works but after animations finished.    

        $('.contents').fadeIn(1000);

    });

        function newpage() {

            window.location = newLocation;

        }

    });
```

I'm not sure what else to try. The only thing that I can think of is that the complete callback is bugged for fadeOut.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do here? The test code seems to be confusing things :)

Comment: I'm trying to transition between the pages by fading out, changing to the next page and fading in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I've worked it out but thanks for all you advice.

Here's the fixed Jquery bit:

```
$('.contents').fadeOut(1000, function(){

    newpage();

    location.reload(); 

});
```

Basically the page needed to be reload in order to load the new part of the page. It then runs the first part of the script again which is responsible for fading in the the page.

Answer (score 2):

since javascript is asynchronous. But you cant change location of page. then the first change will happen;

change your code like this. this should work.

```
 $('.contents').fadeOut(1000, function(){
newpage();
$('.contents').fadeIn(1000, newpage); });
```

Comment: The original code was for testing only. It is obviously pointless to change the current page URL twice (which is what `newpage` does) :)

Comment: Yeah and even with the addition of function(){ newpage(); it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: you put an alert on newpage you  just comment what you have and try what happens

Answer (score 0):

adding proper timing between actions will solve the problem

```
 $('.contents').fadeOut(800, function(){
   newpage();
   $('.contents').fadeIn(100, newpage); });
});
```

basically here what you have doing is calling the anchor and it will call the relavent scroll position.  using jquery scroll you can get smooth results

Answer (score 0):

That's because Javascript is not waiting for FadeOut to finish, so it starts both fadeOut and fadeIn at the same time.

you need to put FadeIn in the callback function of FadeOut if you want to sequentially call them :

$('.contents').fadeOut(1000, function(){ 
[.. your functions .. ] 
$('.contents').fadeIn(1000, newpage); } 
 );

Comment: I understand that but even whilst doing that the page isn't redirected to the anchor whilst the page is fully faded out. It's only redirected after the initial page has been faded back in.

Comment: But I am not sure I understand. You want your page to fadeIn when you open it, then when you click on an anchor, you want it to fadeout, then load the anchor link, then fadeIn ?
Why do you need the second fadeIn then ? the window.location will reload your jquery document.ready() function.
So you just need to make sure that all pages have the same jquery script ready, and just get rid of the second fadeIn, and use the window.location as callback of the fadeOut().

Comment: The site is a single page so when the anchor is clicked it goes to the anchor point on the same page. What I am trying to do is instead of having the link between the anchor points be sudden I want to animate it with a fadeOut fadeIn. You're right, if I were using multiple pages then this script would work.